# Saving and comparing rounded numbers for MATLAB

Tags: matlab, scientific-notation

So i'm creating a function that is trying to compare decimal numbers with scientific notation. I am trying to round them off and saving them into new variables.

What I did is this...

```
>> digits(3);

>> Y = vpa(0.000036856864)

    Y =

    3.69e-5

>> Z = vpa(0.000036857009)

    Z =

    3.69e-5

>> eq(Y,Z)

    ans =

     0
```

Technically the new rounded decimal is saved unto Y and Z, so when I compare the two variables, it gives me 0, but it should be 1. How can I fix this to make sure that the answer equals to 1?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values returned by `vpa` aren't actual numbers - they're symbolic objects that still contain the original value of the number (before rounding). To compare the two, you should convert them back to double:

```
Y = double(vpa(0.000036856864))
Z = double(vpa(0.000036857009))
eq(Y,Z)
```

which should return 1